# Why is my R code so slow to generate a multi-line and bar plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working on making some rather involved plots that combine several data sets in R. `ggplot2` is working great for this endeavor, but man is it slow. I realize that I am working with a large number of data points, but I think I have an arbitrary bottleneck somewhere. Let me explain...

I have 10 different vectors, each 150,000 entries long. I want to use ggplot2 to create a figure with these on the command line, and have the resulting png saved to disk. Each of the 10 vectors will be different colors and some will be lines and some will be bars. The code looks like this:

```
bulk = data.frame(vector1=c(1,5,3,5,...), ... vector10=c(5,3,77,5,3, ...))
png(filename="figure.png", width=4000, height=800)
ggplot(bulk, aes(x=vector1), aes(alpha=0.2)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=vector2), color="red", stat="identity") +
geom_bar(aes(y=vector3), color="black", stat="identity") +
..................
geom_line(aes(y=vector10), color="black", size=1) +
scale_y_log10()
```

Please keep in mind I have 10 vectors, each 150,000 entries long, so I have 1.5M data points to plot. However, I am on an 8 core, 4Ghz/core machine with 32GB RAM, but R is using almost no RAM and only 1 core. This is expected, since as far as I know this process can't be multithreaded, but should the rendering really take ~1 hour per figure?

It feels like something about my code is arbitrarily inflating this processing time. Especially since the same problem with 20,000 entries per 10 vectors only takes about 20 seconds. Scaling it up takes way more than linearly scaled time.

Does anyone have solution or suspicion for this question? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you really want to plot all 1.5 million points?  Why not do some sampling or use a plot that aggregates data (a boxplot would be ideal it seems...)

Comment: I know what you mean, but unfortunately I really do want to plot all of the points. It is for publication quality graphics, so if I must wait for the render time I will, but was hoping to find something I could do to make the process speedier.

Comment: I don't know that this will speed things up, but using data in `long` format rather than `wide` format and letting `ggplot` do its thing with `color` and `groups` may help... but generally it takes a long time to plot 1.5 million dots for anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want or need to plot that many points you have to use `base` R. `ggplot` is very slow with medium to large data sets. This issue is [known](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-final-part/) , I don't  know if things has changed performance wise since then. Using a faster machine won't make a much of a difference either. Try base R. In my experience its much much faster even for very large infographics and visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

Some thing to consider is that different geom's take more or less time, and for some reason that I can't really work out, geom_bar is one of the slowest (along with geom_area). Try using a different geom, at least when protyping the plot. You can switch to bar for the final production plot.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it seems like adding the `alpha` argument slows down the plot generation substantially.

For instance, in a project I'm currently working on, I'm plotting a map of 31 000 data points. On top of this, I add a layer of another 6000 data points. If plotted normally, this takes 1.2 seconds. If the 6000 data points are plotted with `alpha=0.7`, it takes 12.6 seconds. Experimenting with different settings along `shape` and `size` does not nearly affect the computation time as drastically.